# Recive socket data java

Tags: java, sockets

Why it not recive  data from server and from  client to server?  My method   "odbierz" is bad?  I would like sent data from  server to client,  then client sent  data to server  on change.

Client class

```
public class Klient {

    private Socket sock;
   private PrintWriter out;
   private BufferedReader in;



 public Klient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
 {
      sock=new Socket("localhost",50007);                                                      
      System.out.println("Nawiazalem polaczenie: "+sock);  
      in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
      out=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true); 
 }
 public void wyslijDane(int numerKart) throws IOException
 {
        System.out.print("<Wysylamy:> ");                                                

          out.print(numerKart);
          out.flush();
          System.out.println("Wyslano kartę" + numerKart);
 }

 public void odbierz() throws IOException
 {
          String str;

             if(in.ready())
             {
                 while(true)
                 {
            str=in.readLine();  
            System.out.println("<Nadeszlo:> " + str);
                 }
             }
             else 
                 System.out.println("Zajetre");

 }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException                            
   {                                                                                   

  } 
}

public class Server
{
    public static final int PORT=50007;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket sock;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;


public  Server() throws IOException
{

  server=new ServerSocket(PORT); 
  System.out.println("Nasluchuje: "+ server);  
  sock=server.accept(); 
  System.out.println("Jest polaczenie: "+sock);   
   in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
  out=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);                                        


 public void wyslijDane(int numerKarty ) throws IOException
 {
       System.out.print("<Wysylamy:>   ");                                                
         out.print(numerKarty);
         out.flush();
         System.out.println("Wyslano kartę" + numerKarty);
   }

   }
```

Comment: Methods in another language than English increase the complexity to understand and follow the Algorithm... translate and edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how and where you are calling the `odbierz()` method, but `while(true)` is an infinite loop, that's probably why your program is not working.

Try removing the loop:

```
public void odbierz() throws IOException {
      String str;

       if(in.ready()) {
           str=in.readLine();  
           System.out.println("<Nadeszlo:> " + str);
       } else { 
           System.out.println("Zajetre");
       }
}
```

Comment: Ok now working, but i have yet one problem.   I sent data from server and receive  as  I show, but  if  sent e.g  int=5  gets in client e.g 51 etc.

e.g  server: sent int 13
        client : recive from server  INT 49

Comment: Those number are the ascii values of the integer you sent. To get the integer instead of its ascii value you have to use `out.println()` instead of `out.print()`.

Comment: I tryed it with your code and it works... You have to send the data with `out.println(numerKarty);` and read it with `String str = in.readLine();`.  And since your first question has been answered, could you approve the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Why  I must  receive  as String ?

Comment: You can receive it as an Int if you want... You just have to use `out.write(numerKarty);` to send the data and `int str = in.read();` to read the data.

Comment: last question!  how i can receive  object ? I sent through out.print(Object)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93395/discussion-between-thecazziator33-and-pekus).